# can't see Date/Time in the cursor position while plotting a graph with matplotlib. Getting error as "DateFormatter found a value of x=0"

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, timestamp

*I have a timestamp list like:*

```
['2018-06-28 20:00:00', '2018-06-28 20:00:05', '2018-06-28 20:00:10', '2018-06-28 20:00:15', '2018-06-28 20:00:20', '2018-06-28 20:05:30']
```

I am plotting graph like this, where timestamp and iops is a list like:

```
p1, = host.plot(timestamp[0:], iops[0:], "b-", label="IOPS")
```

I have set x_lim as:

```
host.set_xlim([timestamp[0],timestamp[-1]])
```

This is what i have done to show timestamp on x axis:

```
_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
_fmt.format_data_short = lambda pos: mdates.num2date(pos).strftime("%Y-%m-%d; %H:%M:%S")
 host.xaxis.set_major_formatter(_fmt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error message reads

> ValueError: DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date.  This usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()

And that is true indeed, because you are plotting strings here and matplotlib cannot know that they carry a meaning as "date" for you.

The solution is to convert them to dates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import  datetime

timestamp= ['2018-06-28 20:00:00', '2018-06-28 20:00:05', '2018-06-28 20:00:10', 
            '2018-06-28 20:00:15', '2018-06-28 20:00:20', '2018-06-28 20:05:30']
dates = [datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for t in timestamp]
y = list(range(6))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p1, = ax.plot(dates, y, "b-", label="IOPS")

ax.set_xlim([dates[0],dates[-1]])

_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
_fmt.format_data_short = lambda pos: mdates.num2date(pos).strftime("%Y-%m-%d; %H:%M:%S")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(_fmt)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: on mouse hover, x axis it shows me only  this format "%d; %H:%M". How can i make it ""%Y-%m-%d; %H:%M:%S". I guess DateFormatter is not working. I am plotting graph against 1 lakh records.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. [I do get the correct format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQUeR.png) in the lower left corner.